# handling "are you sure you want to navigate away from this page" Msg in Selenium 2.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium 2.0
After Submitting a web form, A popup msg comes up with the "are you sure you want to navigate away from this page" message, How do I get selenium to press OK or disable this popup?

I have already tried

```
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
```

or

```
    alert.dismiss();
```

edit:

quick fix, I just overwrote the popup function using JS

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};"); 

    form.submit();
```

this will stop will disable this popup, the same can be done for js alerts, comfirm and prompt boxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this answer helps:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=27#c6

Overall, the thread raises a similar concern as yours.  You are trying to handle this as an alert, see if you can handle this as a js confirmation dialog.