# Python and Selenium - Disable alert when leaving page

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Using **Python 3** and **Chromedriver**.

Suppose an automated python program is surfing the web, fetching stuff from different sources.

Suppose any of those websites fires an *"Are you sure you wanna leave this page?"* alert.

Key word: **any** (in a random way) of those websites.

**Question**:

How may I set up the program to handle those alerts, by always saying: "yes, i want to leave this page".?

**--- UPDATE ---**

**Possible approach**:

Based on the comment below I am now doing:

```
def super_get(url):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};")
```

And now use `super_get()` insetad of the standard `driver.get()`

Can you think of any more efficient or cleaner way of doing it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820377/handling-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-msg-in-selenium

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you. My obsession with searching for "python" made me not see the java approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Disable the alert on before unload**:

```
def super_get(url):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};")
```

And now use `super_get(whatever_url)` insetad of the standard `driver.get(whatever_url)`

**Disable all alerts in page**:

```
def super_get(url):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.execute_script("window.alert = function() {};")
```

Hope it helps somebody. Cheers.

Comment: does not work. window alerts can be on the page prior to script runs. needs a browser extension to do this or a config parameter

Answer (score 0):

**Goal**
Get all listeners by getEventListeners(window)['beforeunload'] and remove them all.

**Step1. Put DOMDebugger.getEventListeners to window['getEventListeners']**

VB.NET

```
Dim myChromeDriver as ChromeDriver = getMyDriver()
myChromeDriver.ExecuteChromeCommand("Runtime.evaluate", New Dictionary(Of String, Object)() From {
{"expression", "window['getEventListeners'] = getEventListeners;"},
{"includeCommandLineAPI", True}})
```

We don't need the result value of this Command.

includeCommandLineAPI=True is required or it will throw exception because getEventListeners is an CommandLineAPI that is undefined in script execution context

**Step2. Remove all listeners**

```
Dim jsCmd As String = "var eventlistener = window['getEventListeners'](window)['beforeunload'][0];" &
"    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', " &
"    eventlistener.listener, " &
"    eventlistener.useCapture); "
myChromeDriver.ExecuteScript(jsCmd)
```

Run this script until getEventListeners(window)['beforeunload'] is empty.

This script will throw exception when all listeners removed, you can fix it.

**Finally**

```
oDriver.Navigate.GoToUrl("https://www.google.com")
```

The "Are you sure.." alert should disappear.