# selenium chromedriver prevent unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }

Tags: python, selenium, dom, selenium-chromedriver

i'm trying to prevent this alert,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 171, in <module>
    main()
  File "app.py", line 109, in main
    clipper = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.btn")
  File "/home/blaster/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 605, in find_elements_by_css_selector
    return self.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/home/blaster/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 983, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "/home/blaster/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/blaster/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 241, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
  (Session info: headless chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ab2a9a23218b282151362a66cd662),platform=Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64)
```

I have tried to use (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45288632/9137919)) :

```
driver.execute_script("window.alert = function() {};")
```

but it doesn't work, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
  (Session info: headless chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ab2a9a23218b282151362a66cd662),platform=Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64)
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.35*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

- You are using *chrome=65.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.37*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v64-66**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.35*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.37**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v65.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.37 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your page still has `beforeunload` handler which prevents the driver from navigating to another page.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45288632/3676469) but it doesn't work for me either. I giess this is happening because `beforeunload` which is set with jQuery should be cleared with jQuery too:

```
# clear beforeunload hook if you set it with jQuery
page.execute_script("$(window).off('beforeunload')")

# clear onbeforeunload if you set it with plain JS
page.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};")
```